# Make navbar item active in Django Template

Tags: python, django

i'm creating menu with forloop and i need to add active class after click.

```
{% for menu in TopMenu %}
      <li><a href="/content/{{menu.slug_link}}">{{menu.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

i tried to use django template inheritance but it didn't work. any solutions?

```
{% for menu in TopMenu %}
      <li {%if activeflag == '{{menu.slug_link}}' %} class="active"    {%endif%} ><a href="/content/{{menu.slug_link}}">{{menu.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: did you check why activeflag does not equal the slug_link ? maybe there's a formatting problem there

Comment: i checked and they are equal

Comment: maybe `{% if` instead of `{%if`, also for the endif

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: maybe forloop is a main problem here?

Comment: can't you do the check in the view function and add the active class there only to the selected menu and then have class="{{menu.classes}}" and have that empty for all but the active class ?
The idea of templating is to have as much of the operations on the code side, not in the template.

Comment: i have created context processor for this navbar i don't have view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `{{ }}` when using the `if` tag.

Try:

```
{% if activeflag == menu.slug_link %} class="active" {% endif %}
```